# importing functions in python from another script I made

Tags: python, function, import

I'm kind of stuck at a problem where my teacher wants me to import functions from another script

```
def readint():
    prompt = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    print(" You entered: ",prompt," and the type is", type(prompt))
```

and then on the other program I can get it to import like

```
import test 

test.readint()
```

but when I try to get it exactly how she wants

```
test.readint(prompt)
```

I can't seem to get it to work. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
def readint(prompt):
prompt = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
print(" You entered: ",prompt," and the type is", type(prompt))
return prompt
```

any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you import the other script? Also, you don't seem to be grasping the purpose of function parameters.

Comment: Yes I imported the other script and I am struggling with functions. I have to do it for 3 separate functions

Comment: @Austin. You are missing the import. If `readint()` is in file named `test.py` do `from test import *` in the file where you plan to use `test.readint()`.

Comment: Using the namespace like `test.readint()` would actually require `import test`, not `from test import *`.

Comment: @Austin: If the suggestion above is not working you might want to show more code and how you have your files structured.

Comment: I did import the file "test" sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: You are right. I was going to suggest `from test import readint` but he needs to use it as `test.readint()`  and did not correct the import statement. Good catch!

Comment: `import.test` is wrong. Did you copy your code accurately?

Comment: You don't need an `__init__.py` for a simple import.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having problems with the commas in the print statement.

When I ran your initial program, I got this:

```
>>> 
Enter an integer: 3
(' You entered: ', 3, ' and the type is', <type 'int'>)
```

Which doesn't seem to be like what you wanted (it's a tuple)

What you seem to want to print is the string,

```
You entered: 3 and the type is <type 'int'>
```

To do this, you need to cast your variables to strings.

---

**test.py**

```
def readint(prompt):
    prompt = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    print ("You entered: " + str(prompt) + " and the type is " + str(type(prompt)))
    return prompt
```

**main.py**

```
import temp

prompt = None
temp.readint(prompt)
```

Note the `+` operators and `str` casts

---

For me, this outputs the following:

```
>>> 
Enter an integer: 3
You entered: 3 and the type is <type 'int'>
```

Which looks to be what you are looking for.

---

As a side note, I'm not sure why you want to pass in the `prompt` variable because it can be left out and there is no reason to have it in there. Simply removing it from the function definition and not passing it in is perfectly valid:

```
def readint():
    ...
```

and

```
import test
test.readint()
```

---

Happy Coding!

--Elipzer

Answer (score 0):

First off, instead of printing the result to the screen when you get the value of the prompt, try returning it as a string. That way, you can assign the return value to a variable and access it later. Pretty neat, huh? Your second attempt already had it, but there were two little problems:

There's no point in passing an argument to this function. This is because `input()` already stores a value in a variable, so there'd be no point in passing an argument, you could just create a function variable and store it in there. Also, there'd be no point in doing `" and the type is",type(prompt))`. The reason for this is because we already know it's an integer: you converted the result of `prompt` to an integer after you got it's string value. If you passed a value to prompt that couldn't be converted to integer, you'd get a `ValueError`. So, try using this code:

```
def readint():
    prompt = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    return "You entered " + str(prompt)
```

That way, in your other file you can do this:

```
>>> import test
>>> a = test.readint()
Enter an integer7
>>> a
'You entered 7'
>>>
```

(Keep in mind that the three > symbols aren't python code, it comes from the shell)
If you were to enter a invalid value to be converted to an integer, it'd raise a `ValueError`. How can we prevent this? You can use a `try`, `except` statement. Basically, what this does, is it tries to do something, then, if an exception is raised during that process, it does something else.

So, all in all. Your code would look like this:

```
def readint():
    try:
        prompt = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid value! It must be a number."
    return "You entered " + str(prompt)
```